# How to animate 3D blocks in all 3 dimensions for website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

How would I animate three dimensional shapes upon the movement of the mouse so that the blocks move in the x, y, and z directions as seen on the homepage screen of this site http://tomerlerner.com/?

Answer (score 0):

Line 160 of the source code includes three.min.js - they're using the [three.js](https://threejs.org/) library for 3d graphics.

Comment: Where is their code for how they actually animated the graphics?

Comment: Going along with the prior, do you know how they programmed the heading text to change from white color to grey when the white blocks are under it?